# Plot bilinear interpolated gridded data spatially on a map

Tags: matlab, plot, grid, interpolation, surface

I am using the following code to plot gridded data on a map over a region but I would like to know how to plot the interpolated data so that I get continuous data plotted over the region and the data does not look gridded. 'lat' and 'lon' are vectors (1x21 and 1x33) containing the latitude and longitude coordinates respectively.

```
ax = worldmap(latlim, lonlim);
S = shaperead('landareas','UseGeoCoords',true);
surfacem(lat, lon, ans');
geoshow([S.Lat], [S.Lon],'Color','black');
```

I am seeing a lot of documentation on using interp2 but I am not getting mine to work even when I try to create a meshgrid using lat and lon (cannot attach the data). I do the following with interp2:

```
LON,LAT] = meshgrid(unique(lon),unique(lat));
interp2(lon, lat, testdata', LON, LAT);
```

That gives me a result but I then want to plot it over a region without it looking gridded. testdata is a 33x21 matrix. Any ideas? I have seen some examples here on interpolation but I am not sure how to apply it conveniently with the data I have. I am surprised that there is not more information on this or why I am just sucking at finding the answer!

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us **all of your code**, including the `interp2` calls you are making.  You aren't using it properly, so I'd like to see what commands you're using before `interp2`.

Comment: Of course. I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: Any idea with this rayryeng?